# Database solution to store and aggregate vectors?

Tags: mongodb, vector, database

I'm looking for a way to solve a data storage problem for a project.

**The Data:**

We have a batch process that generates 6000 vectors of size 3000 each daily. Each element in the vectors is a DOUBLE. For each of the vectors, we also generate tags like "Country", "Sector", "Asset Type" and so on (It's financial data).

**The Queries:**

What we want to be able to do is see aggregates by tag of each of these vectors. So for example if we want to see the vectors by sector, we want to get back a response that gives us all the unique sectors and a 3000x1 vector that is the sum of all the vectors of each element tagged by that sector.

**What we've tried:**

It's easy enough to implement a normalized star schema with 2 tables, one with the tagging information and an ID and a second table that has "VectorDate, ID, ElementNumber, Value" which will have a row to represent each element for each vector. Unfortunately, given the size of the data, it means we add 18 million records to this second table daily. And since our queries need to read (and add up) all 18 million of these records, it's not the most efficient of operations when it comes to disk reads.

Sample query:

```
SELECT T1.country, T2.ElementNumber, SUM(T2.Value) 
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
WHERE VectorDate = 20140101
GROUP BY T1.country, T2.ElementNumber
```

I've looked into NoSQL solutions (which I don't have experience with) but seen that some, like MongoDB allow for storing entire vectors as part of a single document - but I'm unsure if they would allow aggregations like we're trying efficiently (adding each element of the vector in a document to the corresponding element of other documents' vectors). I read the $unwind operation required isn't that efficient either?

It would be great if someone could point me in the direction of a database solution that can help us solve our problem efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: MongoDB can do these aggregations and I think would be a decent fit here. It's not very much data so for a daily reporting purpose I think directly inserting the records as documents with 3000 fields and then using the aggregation pipeline to compute the sums will be fine. There's a 16MB limit to single documents in MongoDB but unless your fields are very large that should fit 3000 fields.